# Why is this Linq function returning true when it is not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, lambda

I have a "micro class" I wrote for doing some quick data manipulation.

Here is the Item:

```
class AEmp {
  public AEmp() {
    Parts = new AParts();
  }
  public string Badge { get; set; }
  public AParts Parts { get; set; }
  public int Days { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the List:

```
class AEmps {
  private List<AEmp> list;
  public AEmps() {
    list = new List<AEmp>();
  }
  public AEmp this[string badge] {
    get { return list.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Badge == badge); }
  }
  public void Add(AEmp item) {
    if (!Contains(item.Badge)) {
      list.Add(item);
    }
  }
  public bool Contains(string badge) {
    return (list.Where(o => o.Badge == badge) != null);
  }
  public int Count { get { return list.Count; } }
  public AEmp Owner(string serialNo, DateTime startDay, DateTime nextDay) {
    return (list.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Parts.Contains(serialNo, nextDay)));
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is when I go to add new items to the list. I do not want to add an item if it already exists, so I am checking it with my `Contains` method.

The list is empty (Count = 0), so `list.Where(o => o.Badge == badge) != null)` should return **FALSE**.

Right?

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: LINQ will never return a `null`, only an empty sequence, so your `Contains` method will always return `true`.

Comment: A query result with no elements is still a query result, not `null`. You want to use `Any()`.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek While we're talking the extension methods here, the `*OrDefault` calls can.

Comment: badge looks like a key in the collection. Why did you use `List<>` instead of `Dictionary<badge,AEmp>`? `this[]` and `Contains()` would be more efficient

Comment: Among other things, `this[badge]` will throw a NullReferenceException if the item isn't found if I use `Dictionary<badge,AEmp>`. `List<>` just returns a null value. *List* just seems friendlier than the *Dictionary*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Right?

Wrong. An empty sequence is represented as exactly that... an empty sequence. That's not the same as a null reference. Instead, it's a sequence that you can call members on as normal - you just won't get any results. Heck, as LINQ is lazy the sequence doesn't even *know* whether or not there are any elements until you try to ask for them. `Where` couldn't possibly return `null` and still execute lazily.

I think you want [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) instead.

```
return list.Any(o => o.Badge == badge);
```

Note that in general, using an empty sequence (an empty list, empty array etc) is cleaner than using a null reference - it allows callers to have one path which will work either way, rather than having to check for nullity at every step.

Comment: What happened to all the others who answered on here? Maybe you scared them off! :) So, you called this LINQ and I had it tagged as Lambda. Are the two one in the same?

Comment: @jp2code: No, they're not. LINQ uses lambda expressions a lot, but lambda expressions are simply part of C# syntax allowing you to express either a delegate or an expression tree efficiently.

Comment: @jp2code: `Any` is a member of `System.Linq.Enumerable` which takes in a predicate (`Func<T,bool>`).  `o => o.Badge == badge` is a lambda expression representing that predicate.

Answer (score 3):

You answered your own question. 
The list is empty (Count == 0), not NULL.

so your code should be

```
list.Where(o => o.Badge == badge).Count() == 0
```

Comment: My error was believing `list.Where(o => o.Badge == badge)` would return NULL if there was no match.

Comment: @jp2code it will never return null. `Empty` **is not equal to** `NULL`.

Comment: `Where...Count() == 0` is inefficient (and more verbose than necessary).  This pattern forces the application to evaluate the predicate on every element of the enumerable, whereas `Any` breaks out once it finds the first matching element.

Answer (score 2):

because you have instantiated `list` in the constructor causing it not to become `NULL`.

maybe you mean,

```
list.Where(o => o.Badge == badge).Count() != 0
```

Comment: No, that would mean a `NullReferenceException` when accessing `list` if it wasn't. Your answer addresses the real, different issue, however.